# Show that , at a local max or min of ||r(t)||, the vector r'(t) is perpendicular to r(t)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This seems to just be just saying that the gradient of r(t) is 0 at a local max or min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $||\vec{r}(t)||$ can only be positive or zero, you can work with $||\vec{r}(t)||^2 = \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}$.  If you differentiate $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}$ with respect to  $t$ and set that equal to zero, what do you find?

[Note: A physical example of this would be the position vector of a planet on its elliptical orbit about the Sun, said vector pointing from the Sun to the planet.  At perihelion or aphelion, what is true about the planet's *velocity* vector?]